# VSTO: Testing a PivotField's Orientation

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, pivot-table

I have a VSTO application involving an Excel pivot table where I need to test if a particular PivotField is hidden or not. Initially I tried code as follows:

`if (myPivot.PivotFields(myFieldName).Orientation == Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlHidden)`

That compiled okay, but produced a run time error.
I found that if I changed it to this:

`if (myPivot.PivotFields(myFieldName).Orientation == (double)Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlHidden)`

then it worked as intended.
However, the C# Analyzer generates the following:

`Warning    AD0001  Analyzer 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Diagnostics.RemoveUnnecessaryCast.CSharpRemoveUnnecessaryCastDiagnosticAnalyzer' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' with message 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'.`

And lower down it quotes the file in question as the "SyntaxTree", with the "SyntaxNode" referencing `(double)Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation.xlHidden`.

Does anybody understand why the warning and why I need to cast it as a double?

Thanks

Comment: What runtime error did you get? That will help in answering your question

Comment: The error was as below. I took it to mean that the `Orientation` property of a PivotField is a double.  Hence my adding the cast on the right hand side.    `Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'double' and 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlPivotFieldOrientation'`

Comment: what do you mean as below? I need to see the runtime error.

Comment: Slightly more info in case it helps anybody that comes across this in the future. I was able to confirm that the Orientation property of a PivotField is indeed of type `double`. I expected it to be an `int` because of the enumeration, but that does explain why the cast is needed. Regarding the warning, it may be related to the fact that the Analyzer thinks the cast is unnecessary(?), but regardless I think it's something that I, and anybody else, can safely ignore.